# Multiple calls to MPI-aware functions within the same code

Tags: fortran, mpi, f2py

Please excuse if the answer is obvious, as I am quite new to MPI. I am developing a Fortran module with multiple functions that employ MPI (+OpenMP, but that is not the issue). Functions are completely independent and do not require communication. The simplified structure looks like this (real code is many thousand lines long)

```
module FortFastCount
use omp_lib
use mpi

subroutine FcountDD(...args...)
    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, nproc, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, ierr)
    ...do-stuff-according-to-rank...
    call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end subroutine

subroutine FcountDR(...args...)
    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, nproc, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, ierr)
    ...do-stuff-according-to-rank...
    call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end subroutine
```

This module is compiled with f2py and imported by a python wrapping code (i.e. a package) that adds more functionality. Some of these are

```
import FortFastCount
def countDD(...args...)
   res1 = FortFastCount.FcountDD(...many-args1...)
   res = do_something(res1)
def countALL(...args...)
   res1 = FortFastCount.FcountDD(...many-args1...)
   res2 = FortFastCount.FcountDD(...many-args2...)  #note same function but different args
   res3 = FortFastCount.FcountDR(...many-args3...)
   res = combine(res1,res2,res3)
```

A python script importing the package and calling countDD() or countDR() can be run successfully with mpirun inside a batch slurm script. For example:

```
import package
#read data
res=package.countDD(...args...)
```

This works fine and the fast Fortran functions run perfectly in each MPI process while OpenMP threads nested inside are fired and reduced. But problems appear when we try to use countALL() as above (random segmentation faults, various MPI errors, etc.). It seems to be related with multiple calls to MPI_INIT in the same MPI executable. Questions are:

1. Is this the reason?
2. If so, is there any workaround?

I guess other HPC libraries that offer multiple MPI-aware functions, face the same issue when users need to use two or more of them in the same code

Comment: Start moving the init/finalize calls to your main program. You need to init exactly once and likewise finalize exactly once.

Comment: An alternative if you want to keep the encapsulation is to look into using `mpi_initialized` through which you can detect if `mpi_init` has already been called - though I would prefer the method @VictorEijkhout describes

Comment: That said while it is definitely wrong to call `mpi_init` multiple times I am surprised the symptoms are "random segmentation faults" - can you tell us *exactly* what the "various MPI errors" are?

Comment: Keep in mind that once `MPI_Finalize()` is called, there is no way to call `MPI_Init()` again... That being said, `mpi4py` should call these exactly once for you, so why do it (again?) in Fortran?

Comment: I am not using mpi4py at all. Indeed your suggestions solved the issues: (1) checking with MPI_Initialized() in order to call MPI_Init() only once among all my fast counters, and (2) moving MPI_Finalize() to a separate fortran subroutine that is called from the python code at the very end of everything. Thanks for your help